# Proving that $\left | \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-R_k \right |>\frac{1}{Q_k^2\sqrt{5}}$.

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, continued-fractions

I have to prove this inequality, where $Q_k$ is the $k$-th Fibonacci number and $R_k$ is the $k$-th convergent of $[1;1,1,...]$:

$$R_1=1$$
$$R_2=1+\frac{1}{1}$$
$$R_3=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1}}$$

and so on.

So, from the following properties of the sequence $\{R_k\}$:

$$R_k=\frac{Q_{k+1}}{Q_k}$$
$$R_{k+1}-R_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{Q_{k+1}Q_k}$$
$$Q_{k+2}=Q_{k+1}+Q_k$$

I found that the Fibonacci sequence can be written taking into account only one previous term:

$$Q_{k+1}=\frac{Q_{k}}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5-\frac{4(-1)^k}{Q_{k}^2}}\right)$$

and so in this way I can obtain the exact expression for the error between $R_k$ and its limit value:

$$E_k=\left | \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{Q_{k+1}}{Q_k}  \right | =\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2}\left( \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5+\frac{4(-1)^k}{Q_k^2}} \right).$$

Now, if I try to prove that this last expression verify the claim in the case of $k$ even, I obtain:

$$-\frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{5+\frac{4}{Q_k^2}}\right) >\frac{1}{Q_k^2\sqrt{5}} \Rightarrow 0>\frac{4}{Q_k^4}$$

that is an absurd.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us how you got $$0>\frac{4}{Q_k^4}$$ explicitly?  That is, please expand the last result by quite a bit.

Comment: Plus, I also suspect that the inequality is true only when $k$ is an odd positive integer.

Comment: To support @Batominovski's argument https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(number_theory) and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2058057/prove-the-inequality-left-fracmn-frac1-sqrt52-right-frac1mn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$E_k=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\left|\left(1+\frac{4\,(-1)^k}{5\,Q_k^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1\right|\text{ for }k=1,2,3,\ldots\,.$$
Using Bernoulli's Inequality, we see that
$$\left(1+\frac{4\,(-1)^k}{5\,Q_k^2}\right)^{\frac12}< 1+\frac{2\,(-1)^k}{5\,Q_k^2}\text{ for }k=1,2,3,\ldots\,.\tag{*}$$
This shows that, if $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ is odd, then
$$E_k=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\left(1-\left(1-\frac{4}{5\,Q_k^2}\right)^{\frac12}\right)>\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\left(\frac{2}{5\,Q_k^2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\,Q_k^2}\,,$$
as required.  However, if $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ is even, then (*) proves that
$$E_k=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\left(\left(1+\frac{4}{5\,Q_k^2}\right)^{\frac12}-1\right)<\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\,\left(\frac{2}{5\,Q_k^2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\,Q_k^2}\,.$$
Hence, what you want to prove is not entirely correct, and WolframAlpha confirmed my calculations for $k=1,2,3,4,5$:
$$T_1\approx 1.38\,,\,\,T_2\approx 0.854\,,\,\,T_3\approx1.06\,,\,\,T_4\approx0.979\,,\text{ and }T_5\approx 1.01\,,$$
where
$$T_k:=\sqrt{5}\,Q_k^2\,E_k\text{ for }k=1,2,3,\ldots\,.$$

Comment: So, the original claim was wrong, it is not valid for all natural numbers. Thanks for your time.